# Plotting a graph in C++ window

Tags: c++, graphics, graph

I want to plot a graph out of simple functions/set of coordinates in a window. I know the c++ win32 basics and I can make a simple window with buttons and other control objects. But which is the fastest and easiest library to plot a graph to my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you are using Win32 API (not CLR).

Theory is easy, you need to obain device context withing WM_PAINT message.
You can use main window or any child window (control - static, button) inside main window.

Here are some usefull links:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2078/Guide-to-WIN32-Paint-for-Intermediates

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66250/BeginPaint-EndPaint-or-GetDC-ReleaseDC.aspx

eg:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    LineTo(ps.hDC, 30,30);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
return 0;
```

This will draw line from 0,0 to 30,30

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful answer! I made it work. Now I just have to find a way to make a rectangle where the line is drawn.

Comment: Hi @Janman, no problem, take a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx use it as follows inside BeginPaint and EndPaint : Rectangle(ps.hDC, 0, 0, 30, 30)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the light, easy to use library:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1546/Plot-Graphic-Library